# v-list-item-title text color not changing when active in v-navigation-drawer

Tags: css, vue.js, css-selectors, vuetify.js, vue-router

I am trying to make an application using the Vuetify framework. I am stuck in modifying the CSS properties of v-list-item.

The problem is that when an item is active everything is working as expected only the v-list-item-title text is not displayed. However, if I change the opacity to 1 like below:

```css
.theme--dark.v-list-item--active:hover::before,
.theme--dark.v-list-item--active::before {
  opacity: 1;
  border-left: 3px solid #00ffff;
}
```

then the text is displayed but the background color and left border are lost. So, how can I solve this issue to get the desired result?

I reproduced the issue here: https://codepen.io/domarpdev/pen/ZELyEzP

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Is this your expected output? https://nimb.ws/zlkjfx

Comment: No, I want active nav items with the background color and left border with full opacity.

Comment: @m4n0 I think you just increased opacity a little. But basically, I want the active item background color to be exact as the body background and the left-border-color: #00ffff and text color: #fff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put z-index with `-1` on your `.v-list-item--link:before` class. That worked for me.

Comment: if possible can you explain how setting z-index to -1 made it work?

Comment: Im not sure about your code. You had position absolute on your element which means it dissapeared from the flow. Then you have to put z-index in order to show. Value depends on your parent element or next element that has relative or some other position defined with index on it. Not very good in explaining things. :))